# Lookup and record multiple entries with the same name from a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want the user to type in their username and search, then the search would result in outputting their associated data from another spreadsheet, onto the spreadsheet that they searched from. I know I need a loop with a vlookup, but I don't know how to structure it.

I have developed the vlookup necessary to find the user and it outputs their data, but only one line of it, and the user may have 8 lines associated with their information.

```
Dim wfUser As String
wfSAP = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(uc, Range("wfData"), 1, False)

Dim wfRole As String
wfRole = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(uc, Range("wfData"), 2, False)


    With Range("userData")
        .Offset(0, 0) = wfUser
        .Offset(0, 1) = wfRole
    End With
End If
```

It only finds the first occurrence of their username and records that as opposed to all lines associated with the username

Comment: Vlookup won't return multiple lines. You could potentially use `Range.AutoFilter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```vb
Sub lookupData()
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587450/lookup-and-record-multiple-entries-with-the-same-name-from-a-spreadsheet

Dim arrWfData As Variant: arrWfData = Range("wfData") 'allocate the data to an array
Dim R As Long, X As Long

For R = LBound(arrWfData) To UBound(arrWfData) 'for each row in the array
    If arrWfData(R, 1) = uc Then 'if it matches with <uc>
        With Range("userData") 'allocate the values
            .Offset(X, 0) = arrWfData(R, 1)
            .Offset(X, 1) = arrWfData(R, 2)
        End With
        X = X + 1
    End If
Next R

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at some of your variables as they either don't match or aren't defined in the sample you gave, but try something like this:

```
Dim wfArr(), uc As String, i As Long, f As Integer

f = 0
uc = "User"

'load your wfData range to an array
wfArr = Range("wfData").Value

'loop through the array to find all occurances of specified user
For i = LBound(wfArr, 1) To UBound(wfArr, 1)

    'if the user matches, write the values to userData Range
    If wfArr(i, 1) = uc Then
        Range("userData").Offset(f, 0) = uc
        Range("userData").Offset(f, 1) = wfArr(i, 2)
        f = f + 1
    End If
Next i
```